# Connect 2 node process to fakeredis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using `fakeredis` https://www.npmjs.com/package/fakeredis for e2e testing. So I have to 2 node process. one is the server and the second is for database seeding, I want both to connect to the same redis client. is that possible? It's written in the docs that I should specify host and port but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The stubbed databases are kept in an object inside one of the modules files. That means if you `require` that module twice *inside of the same NodeJS* process, you will get the described behaviour, if you run two processes however, they will run against two different fake redis.

To run two services that are normally run in seperate processes, just create a small module:

```
 // test-env.js
 require("./process1");
 require("./process2");
```

then you can `node test-env` to run them together. (This can however cause side effects, for example configurations of modules might interfer).